# SetTimeout inside a viewChildren queryList

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

https://plnkr.co/edit/2eynVajlNChZXSiK0x2Z?p=info

My code:

```
this.adress.changes.subscribe(res => {

     setTimeout( () => 
        this.form.get('address').push(res.last.form)
      , 0);

   })
```

how can I remove this setTimeout and get it working without setTimout

Comment: please explain more about your issue. Plnkr seems working without `setTimeout` also

Comment: are you sure ? can you check your console please ?  this not works https://plnkr.co/edit/MP6JfQHa2I3ETj9ig6yW?p=preview